# Como detectar quando sai 3 números iguais e mostrar uma mensagem?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

Boa tarde,
Estou a fazer uma raspadinha em ActionScript e PHP. Tenho 9 caixas e quando clico no botão comprar ele vai a um ficheiro PHP e gera num ciclo for um rand de números aleatórios para serem mostrados, quando clicado sobre as caixas, o que pretendo agora e quando sair 3 números iguais automaticamente me indique que venceu e aparecer uma mensagem e contar o valor do prêmio e enviar para a base de dados onde tem os créditos do jogador .

**Codigo PHP**

```
    <?php

    $host   =   "localhost";
    $bd     =   "raspadinha";
    $user   =   "root";
    $pass   =   "";

    try {

        $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$bd.';charset=utf8', ''.$user.'', ''.$pass.'');
        $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $sql_saldo_loaded = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM raspadinha");
    $sql_saldo_loaded->execute();
    $row_saldo_loaded = $sql_saldo_loaded->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $saldo_loaded = $row_saldo_loaded['saldo'];

    if($query == "saldo_loaded"){
        echo "saldo=$saldo_loaded";
    }

    if($query == "valores"){

        $alert = "N�o tem mais Creditos para jogar";

        $sql_saldo_verificar = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM raspadinha");
        $sql_saldo_verificar->execute();
        $row_saldo_verificar = $sql_saldo_verificar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($row_saldo_verificar['saldo'] == "0" ){

            echo "msg=$alert";

        }else{

            for ($i = 0; $i<9; $i++){
                $a = mt_rand(1,9);
                echo "valor" . ($i + 1) . "=$a&";
            }

            for ($i_premio = 0; $i_premio<9; $i_premio++){
                $premio = mt_rand(1,50);
                echo "premio" . ($i_premio + 1) . "=$premio&";
            }

            $sql = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE raspadinha SET saldo = saldo - preco");
            $sql->execute();

            $sql_saldo = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM raspadinha");
            $sql_saldo->execute();
            $row_saldo_ver = $sql_saldo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $saldo_descontado = $row_saldo_ver['saldo'];

            echo "saldo=$saldo_descontado";

        }
    }

    if($query == "saldo"){

        echo "saldo=$saldo_descontado";
    }


    //echo "valor=$rand";

    ?>
```

**Codigo flash**

```
var vars_send:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var valores_rcv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var saldo_rcv:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var saldo_loaded:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

vars_send.query = "saldo_loaded";
vars_send.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/api.php",saldo_loaded,"POST");

saldo_loaded.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        saldo.txt_saldo.text = saldo_loaded.saldo;
    } else {
        trace("Erro do conexao");
    }
};

valores_rcv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        trace(valores_rcv);
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            _level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].txt._visible = false;
            _level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].txt_premio._visible = false;
            cor = new Color(_level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].bg);
            cor.setRGB(0xa2a1a1);
            //
            _level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].txt.text = valores_rcv["valor" + (i+1)];
            _level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].txt_premio.text = valores_rcv["premio" + (i+1)];
        }

        if(valores_rcv.saldo >= 0){
            saldo.txt_saldo.text = valores_rcv.saldo;
        }

    } else {
        trace("Erro do conexao");
    }
};

saldo_rcv.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
        trace(saldo_rcv);
        saldo.txt_saldo.text = saldo_rcv.saldo;
    } else {
        trace("Erro do conexao");
    }
};


for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    _level0["quadrado" + (i + 1)].onRelease = function() {
        cor = new Color(this.bg);
        cor.setRGB(0xFFFF00);
        this.txt._visible = true;
        this.txt_premio._visible = true;
    };
}
/*function randRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
    var randomNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return randomNum;
}*/
iniciar.onRelease = function() {
    vars_send.query = "valores";
    if(valores_rcv.saldo == "1"){
        this.enabled = false;
    }
    vars_send.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/api.php",valores_rcv,"POST");
};
```

Comment: Deixa eu te perguntar, porque não gera 3 rand de 0 a 9 cada, fica mais fácil pra comparar depois

Comment: Pode ser se achar que e melhor faca uma resposta se fizer favor com o codigo alterado e para fucionar com eu pretendo se fizer favor e que eu nao estou a conseguir fazer